# Filtering String to a legit string in C

Tags: c, string, int

I am writing a program in c. The incoming string is like this `*H1W000500`, this is a legit string and I copy the contents of the string after `*H1W` i.e `000500` to an integer type.

But I want filter this string if the string is not legit. For example `*H1W.....` or `*H1W~@#$`, If string is not legit, do not copy content and skip. Only Copy contents if the string is legit as written above.

Here what I am doing, but whenever irrelevant string is there, it copies zero value, which is undesirable.

```
 char ReceivedData[50];
 unsigned int Head1Weight;

 p = strstr(ReceivedData, "*H1W");
 if(p)
 {
    Head1Weight = strtoul(p+4,&ptr,10);
 }
```

Comment: So ... actually check `ptr` afterwards? I mean, that's what it's there for.

Comment: Also note that `strtoul` converts to `unsigned long`, so `Head1Weight` should be declared as this type.

Comment: See melpomene's comment: `if(ptr - p == 10) { /* success */ }` (if you need *exactly* 6 digits). Additionally, you might want the string being terminated by a whitespace: `if(*ptr == 0 || isspace(*ptr)) { /* success */ }`.

Comment: what? I did not understand very well: may be you mean: if (sscanf(ptr,"*H1W%d",&intvar)==1) /*OK*/ else /*NOT OK*/

Comment: Must a valid string have exactly 6 digits?  If not, what is allowed?  May the integer have a sign, leading spaces?  Must the `Head1Weight` fit in `unsigned` range, even if `unsigned is 16-bit?

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but your use of `strstr` can be better expressed with `strncmp` to compare the first `4` chars of `receiveddata`. (if your target string exists in the middle of `receiveddata`, then `strstr` is fine) You also need to provide error checking on your `strtoul` conversion. Putting those pieces together you could do something like the following (note: this is shown for a single value, in a loop, change `return` to `continue` as noted in the comments)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* declare constants, avoid magic number use in code */
enum { PRE = 4, BASE = 10, MAX = 50 };

int main (void) {

    char receiveddata[MAX] = "*H1W000500", *p = NULL;
    unsigned long head1weight;

    if (strncmp (receiveddata, "*H1W", PRE) != 0)   /* cmp 4 chars */
        return 1;   /* you would continue here */

    if (strlen (receiveddata) <= PRE)               /* more chars exist? */
        return 1;   /* you would continue here */

    errno = 0;  /* set errno to known value */
    head1weight = (unsigned)strtoul (&receiveddata[PRE], &p, BASE);

    /* check for error conversions on conversion */
    if ((errno == ERANGE && (head1weight == ULONG_MAX)) || 
        (errno != 0 && head1weight == 0)) {
        perror ("strtoul");
        return 1;   /* you would continue here */
    }

    if (&receiveddata[PRE] == p) {  /* check if chars converted */
        fprintf (stderr, "No digits were found\n");
        return 1;   /* you would continue here */
    }

    printf ("head1weight : %lu\n", head1weight);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/parsetounsigned
head1weight : 500
```

Look it over and let me know if you have further questions.

(note: C generally avoids the use of `MixedCase` and `camelCase` variable names in favor of all lower-case, reserving all upper-case for use with constants and macros. It is style, so it is completely up to you...)

Comment: Note: This passes `"*H1W 00500"`, `"*H1W-00500"`, `"*H1W+00500"`.  What value do you see with `(errno == ERANGE && (head1weight == ULONG_MAX))` vs. `(errno == ERANGE)`?  Or why not simply `if (errno) {` ?

Comment: I get it, but the check was built from the *man 3 strtoul* description of "*unless the original (non‐negated) value would overflow; in the latter case, strtoul() returns ULONG_MAX and sets errno to  ERANGE.*", so I thought it better to include the check described?? Wrong?

Comment: IMO, it is not wrong nor better to include the `head1weight == ULONG_MAX` test, but unnecessarily more complex. I was seeking your rationale.  IAC, it is good to show testing of `errno` in some fashion.

Comment: BTW: `"*H1W000500x"` passes this code too as there is not detection against extra text.  OP's goal is unclear on this point.

Comment: Agreed, he is apparently getting a stream of data from somewhere, it sounds like either a socket or tcp connection, but beyond the one example of what the data will look like, the rest is unclear.

Comment: In general, I have yet to see even 1 tightly defined validation request on SO and not that often in the _real world_.  Validation usually means [Calvinball](http://calvinandhobbes.wikia.com/wiki/Calvinball): I'll make up the details as time goes on.  In my experience, it is better to err on too tight a validation than too loose.  Once a product is released with loose specs, too many customers rely on abusing the corners that were not exercised.  Enjoy the week-end.

Comment: Point well taken - short, concise, effective validation, is less prone to morphing into ineffective bloat. The argument for an `errno` check only is the concise and effective choice if there is no distinct handling based on the `ERANGE` checks (and there is none here). Good discussion, and to you too, enjoy the weekend `:)`

Answer (score 0):

From the Linux man page on [strtoul](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul).

> If there were no digits at all, strtoul() stores the original value of nptr in *endptr (and returns 0).

So if, after the `strtoul`, `ptr` is the same as the starting pointer, you know there were no legitimate characters.

```
char* ptr;

unsigned long Head1Weight = strtoul(p + 4, &ptr, 10);
if (ptr == p + 4)
{
    // There were no digits
}
else if (strlen(ptr) > 0)
{
    // There were characters in the string after the end of the number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP's `p = strstr(ReceivedData, "*H1W"); if(p) {` is insufficient as it passes `strstr("abcd12*H1W", "*H1W")`, although it is a start.

---

OP has validation goals that are not specific enough.  "the contents of the string after *H1W i.e 000500 to an integer type."

1. "+123", "-123", " 123" evaluate to integers, are they valid?
2. "123  " can evaluate to an integers, is that valid?
3. The sample *implies* the numeric part should be exactly 6 decimal digits, yet that is uncertain.
4. Sample code uses `unsigned`, could that be 16-bit?  Only "000000" to "065535" valid?
5. "-123" converts successful via `strtoul()`, valid for this goal?
6. should this pass "*H1W000500xyz"?  Is extra text allowed or to be ignored?

---

This is *common* in writing code as the specifications initially have interpretation issues and then tend to evolve.

Code should allow for evolution.

---

Let us start with `*H1W` followed by exactly 6 decimal digits with `sscanf()`.  Code below uses `"%n"` to record the scanning position after checking for digits.  This approach needs additional work should `PREFIX` contain `%`.

```
  // PREFIX should not contain %
  #define PREFIX "*H1W"
  #define DIGIT_FMT "%*[0-9]"
  #define VALID_LENGTH 10

  char ReceivedData[50];
  unsigned long Head1Weight = 0;

  int n = 0;
  sscanf(ReceivedData, PREFIX DIGIT_FMT "%n", &n);

  if (n == VALID_LENGTH && ReceivedData[VALID_LENGTH] == '\0') {
    Head1Weight = strtoul(ReceivedData + sizeof PREFIX - 1, NULL, 10);
  }
```